# next / previous entry linking

Tags: pagination, links, next-prev, sort

I am trying to create links to the next and previous entries NOT using pagination.

I tried the plugin Next / Previous Links Anywhere from McFly but it is not working as described and no longer supported.

Can anyone suggest another plugin that takes the current entry ID from a single page entry and provides a link to the next and previous entries based on the sort order?

Answer (score 1):

```
{exp:channel:next_entry channel="blog"}
    <a class="newer" href="{path=blog}"><span>Newer</span></a>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
{exp:channel:prev_entry channel="blog"}
    <a class="older" href="{path=blog}"><span>Older</span></a>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following plugin: http://www.intoeetive.com/index.php/comments/entry-linking-plugin-for-ee-2.x

Comment: For others that stumble on to this post, you should accomplish this by using the entry link tags that come standard with EE. See answer.